# How to annotate mixin in Python

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a free-standing function, that uses `super()`, and using it like this:

```
import typing 
from abc import ABC

class Foo(typing.Protocol):
    def foo(): raise NotImplementedError

def free_foo(child):
    super(child.__class__, child).foo() 

class Base(ABC):
    pass

class Parent1(Base):
    def foo(self): pass

class Child1(Parent1):
    foo = free_foo

class Parent2(Base):
    def foo(self): pass

class Child2(Parent2):
    foo = free_foo
```

How do I annotate `free_foo` function? I need to indicate that `child` is both instance of `Base` and comply with `Foo` protocol?

Comment: Note that ``super(child.__class__, child)`` is inherently broken. It will search in the MRO by skipping the *actual class of ``child``*, starting at the *second* entry no matter which this is. Instead it should skip beyond the *class in which ``foo`` resides*. Right now if you define another ``class GrandChild(Child2): def foo(self): return super().foo()`` the intermediate ``free_foo`` recursively calls itself infinitely.

Comment: This is true, but I cant really find a workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that right order of parent classes would do the trick:

```
from abc import ABC

class FooBase(Foo, Base, ABC):
    pass

def foo(child: FooBase): pass
```

mypy seems happy on this one.